# Bootstrap collapse close other on click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `ng-repeat` from AngularJS in a table.

When I click on a row, there is data that appears just below this row.

The problem is that when I click on another row while one is already expanded, both are expanded.
I would like to close the first one and expand the second one.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="accordion">
        <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-10">Name</th>
                <th class="col-md-1">Collateral</th>
                <th class="col-md-1"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="pack in packages | filter:search" id="row">
                <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{$index}}" data-parent="#accordion" ng-click="expand(pack)">{{pack.name}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"></span></button></td>
                <td><input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedPackage" ng-value="pack" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat-end>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapse{{$index}}">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{indication}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="bb in bananas">
                                    <td>{{bb.name}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You could just use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (see 'Collapse') for simpler handling of bootstrap collapse...

Comment: If there is no other way i'll try this one. thx

Comment: Of course there is, they are doing nothing magic you can't do in there. Maybe you can simply take their handling of bootstrap collapse as a reference for learning? (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/collapse)

Comment: I'll try to use their handling. thx

Answer (score 0):

first you don't need of unique id for it... 
 Just try with https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/collapse 
 or in your case maybe: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/accordion

Good Luck.

Comment: If I don't get a unique ID how do I know which row I should collapse.... I would like to find an other solution than dowloading angular-ui